# How to create new instance with Type?

Tags: flutter, dart

a.dart file

```
class A {}
```

b.dart file

```
class B {}
```

Another file

```
void createInstance(Type x){
   
   return x();  // not working

   return reflectType(x);  // flutter not supported. only dart

   return x.new();  // or as similar solution ??
}
```

Parameter x will can coming A or B or another Type.

Summary, i want to create new instance dynamically of given type (Type)

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot.  Even if you could, what if the specified `Type`s unnamed constructor requires arguments?  What if it doesn't have an unnamed constructor at all?  Have the caller supply a zero-argument callback that constructs their desired type instead (e.g. `createInstance(A.new)` or `createInstance(() => SomeClass.namedConstructor(someArgument))`).

Comment: okey, but different programming langs has support create dynamically and i can control  spesific situations. I mean, i know coming type requirements. Why dont support this flutter or dart? I just wonder

Comment: Which languages?  You can say that you can control the situations, but the compiler doesn't know that.  For `x()` to work, the compiler would need to know that there is an unnamed, zero-argument constructor for *every* `Type`.  The only thing you can do with an `x` is to call methods provided by the [`Type` interface](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Type-class.html), which are very limited.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I creating route structure for usage onGenerateRoute.This structure logic has a route list and coming 'named route'. For example page = "/home", pageType = HomePage. If onGenerateRoute is triggered, coming 'named route' matched in route list. When matched correctly, new instance is creating and if route setting has arguments pass to new creating instance (can be multiple named arguments). In this way, i can create more dynamically and basic routes. Just like Laravel Framework routes.